# c++ class and namespace errors in Visual Studio

Tags: c++, class

I normally program in c++ on linux, but recently I have begun learning game hacking so I have started creating my programs in visual studio. I'm relatively new to c++ having only started learning it this semester in school. I keep getting: "Hello is not a class or namespace name." I tied taking a working program from my linux vm and using it in Visual Studio and still got the same errors.

my code is as follows:

```
#pragma once

#ifndef HELLO_H
#define HELLO_H

#include "stdafx.h"
#include <Windows.h>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

class Hello {
    public:
        Hello();
        void setString(std::string w);
        void print();
    private:
        std::string word;
};

#endif // !1






#include "Hello.h"
#include "stdafx.h"

Hello::Hello() {
    word = "hello world";
}

void Hello::setString(std::string w) {
    word = w;
}

void Hello::print() {
    std::cout << word << std::endl;
}






// HelloWorld.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//
#include "Hello.h"
#include "stdafx.h"


int main()
{
    Hello* word = new Hello();
    word->print();
    word->setString("test");
    word->print();
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What line is it complaining about?

Comment: stdafx must be the first include. Anything above it is ignored. And I'm not sure it's a good idea to include stdafx in a header.

Comment: Thanks, that was it! How else would I include the stdafx; It's automatically created in the header folder so I just included it like that.